# Preserving whitespace with Pygments

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, pygments, trailing-whitespace

I'm currently writing an application that uses Pygments to perform syntax highlighting.  The problem I'm having is any code I process with Pygments has the leading and trailing whitespace in the file removed, and a single line break added to the end.  Is there a way to make Pygments preserve the whitespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to make your own lexer, e.g.

```
lexer = lexers.get_lexer_by_name("python", stripnl=False)
```

and explicitly pass it to `pygment.highlight`.  See the lexers' reference [here](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/).